# Nested mvel script update

Tags: elasticsearch, mvel

I am using this expression to update a nested document:

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/event/docs/cPd4cfqGTe2Hw9sq0qs_NQ/_update' -d '{
"script": "foreach (item : ctx._source.to) { item['read'] = true  }"
}'
```

But it always says classcastexception boolean cannot be casted to String. I tried putting the true in a param, tried 'T', 'true', 'TRUE', TRUE, 1.

Running out of ideas.

The document sample:

```
{
   "prop":"test"
   "to": [{"id": "1", "read":false},
          {"id":"2","read": true}]
}
```

I also tried changing "id" just to test, and it's telling me I can't cast HashMap into string

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/event/docs/cPd4cfqGTe2Hw9sq0qs_NQ/_update' -d '{
    "script": "foreach (item : ctx._source.to) { item['id'] = '3'  }",
}'
```

Answer (score 1):

The script sent to [UPDATE API](http://blog.qbox.io/introduction-to-elasticsearch-scripting) is not right.
I have corrected your script -

```
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/vm/vm/vm' -d '{
   "prop":"test",                                                                                            
   "to": [{"id": "1", "read":false},
          {"id":"2","read": true}]
}'
```

And on updating , use the below script -

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/vm/vm/vm/_update' -d '{
    "script": "for (item in ctx._source.to) {  item.id = 4  }"
}'
```